# Error in fit.Matrix(tcm, model) : inherits(model, "mlapiEstimation") is not TRUE

Tags: r

When I ran `fit(tcm,model)` using `text2vec` in R, it reports an Error in

> fit.Matrix(tcm, model) :    inherits(model, "mlapiEstimation") is not
>   TRUE

Comment: I can send the code if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to run glove$fit_transform(tcm, n_iter).

Comment: If you're trying to get this vignette to work https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/text2vec/vignettes/glove.html and it isn't, replace the line    'glove$fit(tcm, n_iter = 20)' with the above 'glove$fit_transform(tcm,n_iter=20)' and it will work fine. Thanks!